# Search directory for a file, iterating up parent directories if not found

Tags: powershell

**Given:**

`$path = c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5`

I want to search for `var.txt` starting in the lowest child directory (`dir5`).

If `var.txt` is there, do something, if not, search the next level (in this case `dir4`) for `var.txt` and repeat.

**Possibly relevant links:**

[How I could use test-path to check for var.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658073/powershell-return-directories-which-contain-a-specific-file-but-not-fully-recurs)

[Recursion, maybe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677628/recursive-file-search-using-powershell)

**Ideas:**

Somehow using `Split-Path`, in a loop which iterates `-Parent`, and using `test-path` each iteration to check for `var.txt`

---

**Solution:**

Incorporating the solution below with actions, and breaking the loop if not found at the highest directory:

```
$file = ""
$path = ""
while($path -and !(Test-Path (Join-Path $path $file))){
    if($path -eq ((Split-Path -Path $path -Qualifier)+"\")){
        break
    }
    else {
        $path = Split-Path $path -Parent
    }
}
if($path -ne ((Split-Path -Path $path -Qualifier)+"\")){
    #do something
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something, and if so, can you show us? SO is best used as a resource for resolving specific issues when something doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Kai, aplogies.



The purpose was to find the root directory of a project. Through a script, each file in all the sub-directories of the local root directory would be copied over to a network drive, keeping the folder structure preserved. I figured I would incorporate txt file that the script would search for to get the paste destination. However, because a project folder lives in a client folder, and a client can have multiple projects, I would need to parse a file's path from right to left. I started using PowerShell today and only had an idea. My ideas were actuated in the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$path = 'c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5'
while($path -and !(Test-Path (Join-Path $path 'var.txt'))){
    $path = Split-Path $path -Parent
}
Write-Output (Join-Path $path 'var.txt')
```

Assumes that var.txt exists in one of those dirs, and that you know the path.

Comment: Apologies sir - I had upvoted you, but because I have less than 15 reputation I do not think it shows publicly. The question also garnered negative points, insult to injury.

This solution worked as intended. I inserted an `if` and `else` statement within the `while` loop to do given actions.

Answer (score 5):

Try this (recursive method) :

```
function GetPathIfFileExist($pathtosearch, $filename)
{
   if($pathtosearch -eq "")
   {
       "file not founded"
   }
   elseif (Test-Path "$pathtosearch\$filename" )
   {
       $pathtosearch
   }
   else
   {
      GetPathIfFileExist (Split-Path $pathtosearch) $filename
   }
}

GetPathIfFileExist "c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5" "var.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternate solution - is there a benefit of using this recursive method over the while split-path method?

Comment: I dont think there is a really difference, except to readability. Do your choice :)